# Netlify not updating build folder

Tags: web, deployment, web-deployment, netlify

I am using Netlify to deploy my website from GitHub. I have made a few changes to the site and I made a clone of the repository then I used npm install and npm run build. Then I pushed the repo on GitHub and the website does not update with my changes. I am taking over this website for a school club and I'm not sure how they did it in the past. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: there is no need to npm run build in your end. This thing is done automatically by netlify. you should have pushed the changes to your repository and didn't ran npm run build.

Comment: Okay ill try that. Ill make a change and not run npm build.

Comment: I made a change committed it to the main then pulled and pushed to github and it still doesnt update.

Comment: looks like you've messed up pulling or pushing the changes you've made or you should consider looking your netlify application profile thereby check if any errors or something that have shown there. Also if all things won't work simply delete your hosted site and host it again. if you wish you can share the github code then i can give more insights.

Answer (score 0):

You might push your .env file to GitHub. If yes then remove your .env file from the repo of your GitHub.

Comment: It was the privacy setting on the the .json package, but thanks